# Proper directory of the font

Tags: html, node.js, express

im new here and learning to create a webpage.

Im trying to use Raleway font for may exercise in laravel but i think i have a problem in my link. I've tried using this link

```
<link href="../node_modules/raleway-webfont/raleway.min.css">
```

in this location:

[image: see image]

The console also says

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

how can i fix this?

Comment: Didn't you set the directory root to the public folder as suggested? If you did: That directory is not publicly accessible via browser.

Comment: Check your routing...

Answer (score 0):

copy paste it in entry file ie(app.js or index.js) it will  work

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```